# Fit image to a container with a fixed width - ensuring IE11 doesn't stretch or distort them

Tags: html, css

I have a container div that is 150px in width and 100px in length. Using CSS, the logo image that will be chosen by the user will be set to fit this container. I'm using some flexbox styles to center the image and max-width: 100%, max-height: 100% to ensure the image fits in the container. This doesn't work as well for some images in IE11, so I have a IE11-only media query that also adds `flex: 1` in order to fix it.

The problem though is that `flex: 1` fixes the IE11 issue with very wide images overflowing the container. However, it stretches any narrower images that are more vertical in appearance.

```css
.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  align-self: center;
  margin: pxToRem(25px);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none),
(-ms-high-contrast: active) {  
  .logo .logo-image {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Flex 1 fixes this image for IE11 -->
<div class="logo">
    <div class="logo">
        <img class="logo-image"
            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7e/Node.js_logo_2015.svg/1200px-Node.js_logo_2015.svg.png" />
    </div>


</div>

<!-- This image gets stretched by the flex: 1 style -->
<div class="logo">
    <img class="logo-image"
        src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Firefox_logo%2C_2019.svg/1200px-Firefox_logo%2C_2019.svg.png">
</div>
```

Is there a way I can ensure that both very wide images and very tall images work for IE11 without having them get stretched or distorted? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `flex: wrap` to `min-width: 1px` for the IE11 style worked, at least with about a dozen different logos that I've tried:

Updated CSS:

```
.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  align-self: center;
  margin: pxToRem(25px);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none),
(-ms-high-contrast: active) {  
  .logo .logo-image {
    min-width: 1px;
  }
}
```

If you think there's a better way to go about this please let me know.